# How QMediaContent able to show a video when urllib unable to download?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, urllib, qmediaplayer

I have a Qt application to show videos from urls using:

```
player = QMediaPlayer()
...
player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl(video.url)))
...
```

But unable to download the video using the same url with `urllib.request`, response code is always `200` but `Content-Length` is zero.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
rq = Request(video.url)
rp = urlopen(rq)
rp.headers["Content-Length"] # always 0
```

How Qt is able to show video when im failing to download?

**MWE**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from urllib.request import urlopen
import sys

class Test(QVideoWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QVideoWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.setVideoOutput(self)
        self.player.mediaStatusChanged.connect(self.statusChanged)

        self.url = "https://api16-normal-c-useast1a.tiktokv.com/aweme/v1/play/?video_id=v09044190000brfkq160bkbi3ui1oko0&line=0&ratio=540p&media_type=4&vr_type=0&improve_bitrate=0&logo_name=tiktok_m&quality_type=11&source=PackSourceEnum_AWEME_DETAIL"
        self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl(self.url)))


    def statusChanged(self, status):
        if status == QMediaPlayer.LoadedMedia:
            self.player.play()
        elif status == QMediaPlayer.EndOfMedia:
            self.player.play()

    
    def download(self):
        rp = urlopen(self.url)
        if int(rp.headers["Content-Length"]) != 0:
            with open("test.mp4", "wb") as mp4:
                while True:
                    chunk = rp.read(1024)
                    if not chunk: break
                    mp4.write(chunk)
        else:
            raise Exception("Content-Length is Zero")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = Test()
    test.show()
    # uncomment to download
    # test.download()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Could you share the urls?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes, its from tiktok app ```https://api16-normal-c-useast1a.tiktokv.com/aweme/v1/play/?video_id=v09044190000brfkq160bkbi3ui1oko0&line=0&ratio=540p&media_type=4&vr_type=0&improve_bitrate=0&logo_name=tiktok_m&quality_type=11&source=PackSourceEnum_AWEME_DETAIL```

Comment: I can't reproduce anything with that url. On the other hand it seems that you have an XY problem, what is your basic objective?

Comment: @eyllanesc I doing PC version of tiktok using Qt im stuck with ```save video``` button, Qt is able to show the video but when im requesting using ```urllib``` i get nothing.

Comment: mmmm, so a better question should be: how to download tiktok videos with Qt? and in the post you should explain that you can reproduce using QMediaContent (showing a real url as an example) but you have tried to download it with urllib but it fails.

Comment: @eyllanesc I added working example see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several attempts I found that you must set the "user-agent". Qt does not directly handle QMediaPlayer requests but backends like gstreamer on Linux, and these set the user-agent so it works correctly.

I also found that you shouldn't be the user-agent of browsers like "Mozilla/5.0 ..." are probably rejected as a means of protection.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

# ...

class Test(QVideoWidget):
    # ...
    def download(self):
        rq = Request(self.url, headers={"user-agent": "MyApp/1.0"})
        with urlopen(rq) as rp:
            with open("test.mp4", "wb") as mp4:
                while True:
                    chunk = rp.read(1024)
                    if not chunk:
                        break
                    mp4.write(chunk)
```